# Interaction of atoms of the same material

Tags: energy, atoms

So I've been reading a section about energy levels and came across this statement: "As the atoms of a material are brought closer together to form the crystal lattice structure, there is an interaction between atoms that will result in the electrons in a particular orbit of one atom having slightly different energy levels from electrons in the same orbit of an adjoining atom." 
What I don't understand is that how could be an interaction of atoms of the same material occur, if they have the same potential, number of e- and structure. And why would they have a difference in energy levels??

Comment: How could there not be some sort of interaction as they are brought close together? And, if so, how would you not lift the degeneracy?

Comment: But how would they interact if they have same potential. If they have different number of electrons then it is more logical that one is more positive than the other and an interaction would be possible to ocuur but they are the same atoms

Comment: When the electrons of one start to feel the electrons of the other, they interact.  I'm not sure what you mean by "have the same potential", but notice that if the electrons are close enough to interact, then the force law of the system becomes considerably more complicated.